# Windows 10: where to find the current battery level of my wireless keyboard and mouse?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a tiny device plugged in an USB port, that talks to my keyboard and mouse.

In the settings for "Bluetooth & other devices", it seems to appear as `Mouse, keyboard & pen`, and underneath, in a box: `USB Receiver`.

The only corresponding control seems to be: "Remove device"; no further options.

How do I tell the current level of the batteries in these devices?

EDIT: additionally, I have just noticed that my Bluetooth is actually `off`. So however this little USB dongle works, it's separate from Windows' onboard bluetooth.

Comment: Software that provides this function is typically provided by the OEM of the I/O device

Comment: And many manufacturer's do *not* provide any feedback to the user on battery level. That said, low self-discharge NiMH (e.g., *Eneloop*) or alkaline cells often last 6 months or more (I just bought a Logitech mouse with a 2-year warranty on the two alkaline AA cells!), so replace when it starts to behave erratically.